# How to simplify the following summation?

Tags: induction

I doing some derivation for my work. In some textbook, I got the following simplification, $x = \sum_{k=0}^{L-1}\frac{1}{2p+2(k+1)}$ to $x=\frac{2^{L-1}\sum_{k=0}^{L-1}\frac{L!}{k+1}}{\prod_{k=0}^{L-1}2p+2(k+1)}$, where $p$ is constant.

I could get the denominator, but I'm not able to get how the numerator got modified? Is this true simplification using the method of mathematical induction or if its true how it can done?

Please clarify my doubt? Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible that you forgot some $p$ factor at the numerator of the simplified version of $x$?

Comment: No sir. But you suggest modifications accordingly. Thanks, @DavideMorgante

Answer (score 0):

is this:
$$x=\frac{ \sum_{k=0}^{L-1}{\left(\prod_{i\ne k}^{L-1} {2p + 2(i+1)} \right)}}{ \prod_{j=0}^{L-1} {2p + 2(j+1)}}$$
useful?

Comment: I have also got the same expression. Thanks, @Mattia Ghio

Comment: Try with the logarithm function, it trasform productories in summation

Answer (score 0):

For me seems very unlikely that the simplification holds true, there's no dependence on $p$ at the numerator where clearly should be being the denominator just the product of all the denominators without any simplification.
Let us take it easy and try to prove it with a small amount of factors, like $L=3$. In this case we get 
$$x = \sum_{k=0}^2 \frac{1}{2p+2(k+1)} = \frac{1}{2p+2}+\frac{1}{2p+4}+\frac{1}{2p+6} \\ = \frac{(2p+4)(2p+6)+(2p+2)(2p+6)+(2p+2)(2p+4)}{(2p+2)(2p+4)(2p+6)} \\= \frac{3(4p^2)+2(2p\cdot6)+2(2p\cdot4)+2(2p\cdot2)+(4\cdot6)+(2\cdot6)+(2\cdot4)}{\prod_{k=0}^2 2p+2(k+1)} \\=\frac{3(4p^2)+p(8+16+24)+(8+12+24)}{\prod_{k=0}^2 2p+2(k+1)}$$
From your formula, for $L=3$ we have $$2^2\sum_{k=0}^2\frac{3!}{k-1} = 4\left(3!+\frac{3!}{2}+\frac{3!}{3}\right)$$
which clearly is not the same thing we got before

Comment: Yes, I agree with your explanation.

Comment: If this was what were you looking for, you should accept the answer. Here on MSE this gives points to the user who answered as well as letting all other users know that this forum is closed!